# Python: How to decode (utf-8) bytearray object in string format back into string?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, byte

I have a list of data in form:

```
myList = ["bytearray(b'hi')", ...]
```

something like that.

I want to take each value in the list and convert into plain string form. So the given example should output :

```
hi
```

I know you do something like this:

```
data = bytearray(b'hi')
string = data.decode('UTF-8')
```

I am struggling with converting the initial string into a bytearray object to decode it back into the string. Any help?

Comment: how did you create this list ? It seems you converted all to strings. Maybe you should change code which creates this list - and stop converting to string. Now you may have to use `eval("bytearray(b'hi')")` to convert it back from string to bytesarray.  `eval("bytearray(b'hi')").decode('UTF-8')`

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) is what your looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `eval` to first convert the list items into `bytearray` object then call `decode` to convert `bytearray` object back to string.

```py
[eval(each).decode('utf-8') for each in myList]

#output:
['hi']
```